# Flink Keystream slow performance

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an Flink application which uses Kafka as a source, flatmap and aggregation are applied on this stream.

`source` -> `flatmap` -> aggregation(window 5min) -> `sink`

**System specifics:**

- Kubernetes with 100 taskmanagers with 2 taskslots (40GB/taskmanager)
- 1 jobmanager(40GB)

Kafka consumer will consume 20GB/min(2.5M records/min) from 200 partitions.
After `flatmap` 3mb/min(10k records/min) will be available.

So when I test this application only with `flatmap` the stream is significantly fast(this may be because of stateless transformation). But when i apply `keyby`(200 keys) the performance got decreased by 60%. Instead of Kafka consuming 20GB/min its consuming 8GB/min.

```
Stream
    .flatmap(function)
    .keyby(keyselector)
    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5))) 
    .process(new AggFunction())
```

```
public class AggFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<CustomObject, CustomObject, String, TimeWindow> {

  public void process(String key, Context pwf, Iterable<CustomObject> itr, Collector<CustomObject> clctr) throws Exception {
        Map<String, CustomObject> cache = new HashMap();
        itr.for(CustomObject obj) -> {
            //count each object occurrence and save in hashmap
        } 
        //iterate hashmap values and sent to collector
    }
}
```

How to tune performance of this system and make KeyedStream faster? What is the issue here.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `KeyStream` Flink is doing a shuffle/partition operation under the hood. Basically Flink is sending events with same key to the same downstream operator (`process` operation in your case) which is placed in a given slot on a given TaskManager. Since yours Task Managers have only 2 task slots, the shuffle becames expensive because parallel physical instances of the same operators are placed on slots of different Task Managers, and on different machines/pods. So, connections between the `keyBy` and `process` tend to use more network connections.

If you increase the number of slots on each Task Manager then connections between the `keyBy` and `process` will use more memory connections. Of course, there is a trade off on it. I would set to the number of cores available on each machine/pod.

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=#core available
parallelism.default=#core available
```

> So when I test this application only with flatmap the stream is significantly fast(this may be because of stateless transformation). But when i apply keyby(200 keys) the performance got decreased by 60%.

Keep in mind that shuffle/partition operations are expensive. But they are necessary to do aggregate operations for proccessing engines.

A second option is to look on the `KeySelector` that you are using and if you have skew on the `keyBy` transformation. Just look at the Flink dashboard and check if the parallel instances are NOT balanced. If they are not it is probably the case that you have to choose better your `KeySelector` (if it is possible).

A third option which is more advanced is to create your own operator to compute a pre-aggregation before the shuffle phase, i.e.: before the `keyBy` transformation. This transformation does not exist in Flink so you have to call the custom `.transform(your_operator, your_udf)`. The [transform](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#transform-java.lang.String-org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator-) accepts custom operators. The you basically pre-aggregates evnets before to sendo to`keyBy` and reliaves this phase. Your [pre-aggregate operator](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/operator/AbstractMapStreamBundleOperatorDynamic.java) will be something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractMapStreamBundleOperatorDynamic<K, V, IN, OUT>
        extends AbstractUdfStreamOperator<OUT, MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT>>
        implements OneInputStreamOperator<IN, OUT>, BundleTriggerCallback {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6191200344708768482L;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractMapStreamBundleOperatorDynamic.class);

    /** The map in heap to store elements. */
    private final Map<K, V> bundle;

    /**
     * The trigger that determines how many elements should be put into a bundle.
     */
    private final BundleTriggerDynamic<K, IN> bundleTrigger;

    /** Output for stream records. */
    private transient TimestampedCollector<OUT> collector;

    private transient int numOfElements = 0;

    public AbstractMapStreamBundleOperatorDynamic(MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT> function,
            BundleTriggerDynamic<K, IN> bundleTrigger) {
        super(function);
        chainingStrategy = ChainingStrategy.ALWAYS;
        this.bundle = new HashMap<>();
        this.bundleTrigger = checkNotNull(bundleTrigger, "bundleTrigger is null");
    }

    @Override
    public void open() throws Exception {
        super.open();

        numOfElements = 0;
        collector = new TimestampedCollector<>(output);

        bundleTrigger.registerCallback(this);
        // reset trigger
        bundleTrigger.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(StreamRecord<IN> element) throws Exception {
        // get the key and value for the map bundle
        final IN input = element.getValue();
        final K bundleKey = getKey(input);
        final V bundleValue = this.bundle.get(bundleKey);

        // get a new value after adding this element to bundle
        final V newBundleValue = userFunction.addInput(bundleValue, input);

        // update to map bundle
        bundle.put(bundleKey, newBundleValue);

        numOfElements++;
        bundleTrigger.onElement(bundleKey, input);
    }

    /**
     * Get the key for current processing element, which will be used as the map
     * bundle's key.
     */
    protected abstract K getKey(final IN input) throws Exception;

    @Override
    public void finishBundle() throws Exception {
        if (!bundle.isEmpty()) {
            numOfElements = 0;
            userFunction.finishBundle(bundle, collector);
            bundle.clear();
        }
        bundleTrigger.reset();
    }
}
```

Using this operator you pre-aggregates locally events with the same key. The final/global aggregation still have to be perform, but now it will receive less events.

Answer (score 0):

Note that keys in Flink don't correspond to partitions. The architecture is specialized on a high number of keys (e.g. user id or session id). Keys are assigned to key groups. The configured maximum parallelism decides about the number of key groups. It might be that multiple keys are mapped to the same key group which is then assigned to the same slot.

Your key space seems very small (only 200 keys). It might be the case that not all taskmanager slots have work to do. You can fix this by either introducing an artificial key (to increase your key space and spread the load) or by introducing a two level approach as Felipe explained.